# Integral using Partial Fraction Decomposition [solved]

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

I've been having a problem with this integral; although it seems I have the correct answer, It continues to be marked incorrect on an automated grading program. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Evaluate the integral of : $\int \frac{2 x^3 - 4 x^2+ 16 }{x^4+ 2 x^3} \,dx$.

Taking partial fraction: $\int \:-\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{8}{x^3}+\frac{2}{x+2}dx$

Applying sum rule: $-\int \frac{4}{x^2}dx+\int \frac{8}{x^3}dx+\int \frac{2}{x+2}dx$

> $\int\frac{4}{x^2}dx=-\frac{4}{x}$
>
> $\int \frac{8}{x^3}dx=-\frac{4}{x^2}$
>
> $\int \frac{2}{x+2}dx=2\ln \left(x+2\right)$

Simplifying: $-\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{4}{x}+2\ln \left(x+2\right)$

$$ \int \frac{2 x^3 - 4 x^2+ 16 }{x^4+ 2 x^3} \,dx = -\frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{4}{x}+2\ln \left(x+2\right)+C$$

```
Edit: The problem was not doing the absolute value of the ln|x+2|.
```

> Correct solution :$$ - \frac{4}{x^2}+\frac{4}{x}+2\ln|x+2|+C$$

Comment: also try putting 2ln|x+2| instead of 2ln(x+2)

Comment: It seems as though I had tried everything other than doing the absolute value, including finding common denominators and switching the ln() for log() like @Amzoti suggested. Thanks for the solution, Sorry I made such a stupid mistake!

Comment: The solution was $−4x2+4x+2ln(|x+2|)+C$ opposed to $−4x2+4x+2ln(x+2)+C$

Comment: Anytime that you do integral(1/x) it's always ln(abs(x))